# Show DIV based on time of day - PHP

Tags: php, time

The goal is to get a Live Chat link to show on the page during business hours but not show when closed.  The following PHP works on our test server but not our client's server.  Any ideas why it could work on one and not the other?  Both are Apache managed through GoDaddy.

PHP:

```
<style>
    .timeBasedLink {
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $currentTime = date('H:i a');
        $openTime = "8:00 am";
        $closeTime = "6:00 pm";
        $open = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $openTime);
        $close = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $closeTime);
        $open = $open->format('H:i a');
        $close = $close->format('H:i a');
        if ($currentTime > $open && $currentTime < $close)
    { ?>
    display: block;
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    display:none;
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timeBasedLink">
    Put time-sensitive material here.
</div>
```

Comment: LiveChat? That stuff is just annoying. Please don't.

Comment: How does it "Not" work? Error message? Smoke coming from the server??

Comment: Don't put that code in the style. Use it in the actual markup and flip a class on the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the opening/closing time doesn't involve minutes, you can use full integers based off the 24 hour clock. Whereas the opening time is 8 (0800) and the closing time is 18 (1800). Then it's just a simple if statement. I've put the php above the CSS for clarity:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$currentHour = date("H");
$openTime = 8;
$closeTime = 18;
if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentTime < $closeTime){
    $css = 'display:block;';
}else{
    $css = 'display:none;';
}

echo '<style type="text/css">.timeBasedLink {'.$css.'}</style>';
```